# How do I map an array of hashes and output 0 on empty date items?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
items = [
   {:created=>"2013-12-01", :amount=>16611},
   {:created=>"2013-12-02", :amount=>16611}, 
   {:created=>"2013-12-04", :amount=>9428},
   {:created=>"2013-12-05", :amount=>11628},
   {:created=>"2013-12-06", :amount=>4600},
   {:created=>"2013-12-09", :amount=>21756},
   {:created=>"2013-12-10", :amount=>18127}
]
```

You'll notice, there are a number of dates missing in the sequence (3, 7 and 8).

I have a `map` that outputs those hashes into an array of only the amounts for the hashes that match a range of dates:

```
items.select{ |key| (Date.parse("December 1, 2013")..Date.parse("December 12, 2013")).include? Date.parse(key[:created])}.map { |key| key[:amount] }
```

Right now, that outputs the full contents of the `amount` items into an array: `[16611, 16611, 9428, 11628, 4600, 21756, 18127]`

But what I need it to do is insert a `0` for the dates that are missing from the range. So in my example, my range goes from December 1 - December 12. So the output would be:

```
[16611, 16611, 0, 9428, 11628, 4600, 0, 0, 21756, 18127, 0, 0]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Because everyone likes a one-liner:

```
Hash[(Date.parse("December 1, 2013")..Date.parse("December 12, 2013")).map { |x| [x,{:created=>x,:amount=>0}]}+ items.map { |x| [Date.parse(x[:created]),x] }].map { |i| i[1][:amount]}
```

Basically, create an array of the dates we want with empty values, add the real values to the end of the array. Convert to a hash, thereby overriding the earlier empty values where they exist, and then iterate over the result.  In Ruby >=1.9.2 you get the keys out in their original sequence.

```
[16611, 16611, 0, 9428, 11628, 4600, 0, 0, 21756, 18127, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Actually, if you're using ruby >1.9.2 this is perfectly safe.  Ruby >1.9.2 preserves key order.

Comment: Matt's answer is more elegant.  The use of may_fail || safe_default is great.

Comment: Inspired by @Matt answer, `(Date.parse("December 1, 2013")..Date.parse("December 12, 2013")).map { |d| (items.find(Proc.new {{:created=>d.to_s,:amount=>0}}) { |t| d.to_s == t[:created] })[:amount] }` creates missing hashes for the date, which might be useful if you had more than one field you wanted to return.

Answer (score 0):

```
lookup = Hash[*items.flat_map { |it| [Date.parse(it[:created]),it[:amount]] }]

(0..11).map { |i| lookup.fetch(Date.new(2013,12,1)+i,0) }
```

> [16611, 16611, 0, 9428, 11628, 4600, 0, 0, 21756, 18127, 0, 0]

Comment: Nice! Out of curiosity, is there a way to do that in one line?

Comment: `(0..11).map{|i|(items.find{|t|t[:created]==Date.new(2013,12,1+i).to_s}||{})[:amount]||0}`

Answer (score 0):

Given a date range:

```
r = (Date.parse("December 1, 2013")..Date.parse("December 12, 2013"))
```

and assuming the dates in `items` are unique, which appears to be the case, I would do it this way:

```
b = items.each_with_object({}) {|g,h| h[Date.parse(g[:created])] = g[:amount]}
r.map { |d| b[d] ? b[d] : 0 }
   #=> [16611, 16611, 0, 9428, 11628, 4600, 0, 0, 21756, 18127, 0, 0]
```

We first create a hash with elements `k=>v`, each corresponding to an element `h` of `items` such that `k = Date.parse(h[:created])` and `v = h[:amount]`:

```
b = items.each_with_object({}) {|g,h| h[Date.parse(g[:created])] = g[:amount]}
  #=> {#<Date: 2013-12-01 ((2456628j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>16611,
  #    #<Date: 2013-12-02 ((2456629j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>16611,
  #    #<Date: 2013-12-04 ((2456631j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=> 9428,
  #    #<Date: 2013-12-05 ((2456632j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>11628,
  #    #<Date: 2013-12-06 ((2456633j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=> 4600,
  #    #<Date: 2013-12-09 ((2456636j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>21756,
  #    #<Date: 2013-12-10 ((2456637j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>18127}
```

Next we use `map` to convert each member `d` of the range `r` into `b[d]` if `b` contains a key `d`, else `d` is converted to zero.

Alternatively, we could do it like this:

```
items.each_with_object({}) { 
  |g,h| h[Date.parse(g[:created])] = g[:amount] }
    .values_at(*(rng.to_a))
    .map {|v| v.nil? ? 0 : v}
```

After calculating the hash as above, we use [Hash#values_at](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to create an array that contains the values in the hash, plus `nil` for each date in `rng` for which there is no match in `b`:

```
c = items.each_with_object({}) {|g,h|
  h[Date.parse(g[:created])] = g[:amount]}.values_at(*rng.to_a)
  #=> [16611, 16611, nil, 9428, 11628, 4600, nil, nil, 21756, 18127, nil, nil]
```

Lastly, map the `nil`s to zero:

```
c.map {|v| v.nil? ? 0 : v}
  #=> [16611, 16611, 0, 9428, 11628, 4600, 0, 0, 21756, 18127, 0, 0]
```